# selecting random value from column based on distinct values

Tags: sql, sql-server, random, distinct-values

I have following data in  table :-

```
| item    | rate |
-------------------
| a       | 50   |
| a       | 12   |
| a       | 26   |
| b       | 12   |
| b       | 15   |
| b       | 45   |
| b       | 10   |
| c       | 5    |
| c       | 15   |
```

and i need a query which return following output :

```
| item no | rate |
------------------
| a       | 12 |  --from (26 , 12 , 50)
| b       | 45 | --from (12 ,15 , 45 , 10)
| c       | 5  | --from (5 , 15)
```

i.e item_no should be distinct and with randomly one rate value..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        item
    FROM T
)
SELECT
    CTE.item
    ,A.rate
FROM
    CTE
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP(1) 
            T.rate
        FROM T
        WHERE T.item = CTE.item
        ORDER BY CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4)
    ) AS A
;
```

Index on `(item) include (rate)` would help.

Comment: thanks , @Vladimir , your query provides result 3 times faster then other .

thanks to all your their response ...

Comment: @speedyraz, I'm glad you found my answer useful. The relative performance of this approach vs. `row_number` would depend on the distribution of your data (how many rates are there per item) and available indexes.

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to use the row number window function with `item` as the partition.  Then use `ORDER BY NEWID()` within each partition to generate a random ordering, retaining the first row of each `item` partition arbitrarily.

```
SELECT t.item,
       t.rate
FROM
(
    SELECT item,
           rate,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY item ORDER BY NEWID()) AS rn
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

HERE  `NEWID()` is used for  partition to generate a random ordering,
 within partition , it will retain the first row of each item.

```
with cte as
    (

        SELECT item,
               rate,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY item ORDER BY NEWID()) AS rn
        FROM #Table1
        )
        select item,rate from cte where rn=1
```

Comment: It's better to include some context/explanation with code as this makes the answer more useful for the OP and for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

Try this query once.

```
select * into #temp  from (
        SELECT 'a' item,50 rate 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'a',12  
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'a', 26 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'b',12  
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'b', 15 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'b',10 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'c',5  
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'c',15 )as a

    select * from (
    select *,row_number()over(partition by item  ORDER BY newid() )as runm from #temp
    ) as a
    where runm=1
```

Note: The above query gives every time the new output as the newid() generates a new id for every execution .

Answer (score 1):

```
; WITH tb( item, rate)AS(
    SELECT 'a',50 UNION
    SELECT 'a',12  UNION
    SELECT 'a', 26 UNION
    SELECT 'b',12  UNION
    SELECT 'b', 15 UNION
    SELECT 'b',10 UNION
    SELECT 'c',5  UNION
    SELECT 'c',15 
    ) 
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER( PARTITION BY item ORDER BY NEWID())  AS rn FROM tb
    ) t WHERE t.rn=1
```