# Oracle SQL, how to select * having distinct columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I want to have a query something like this (this doesn't work!)

```
select * from foo where rownum < 10 having distinct bar
```

Meaning I want to select all columns from ten random rows with *distinct* values in column bar. How to do this in Oracle?

Here is an example. I have the following data

```
| item    | rate |
-------------------
| a       | 50   |
| a       | 12   |
| a       | 26   |
| b       | 12   |
| b       | 15   |
| b       | 45   |
| b       | 10   |
| c       | 5    |
| c       | 15   |
```

And result would be for example

```
| item no | rate |
------------------
| a       | 12 |  --from (26 , 12 , 50)
| b       | 45 | --from (12 ,15 , 45 , 10)
| c       | 5  | --from (5 , 15)
```

Aways having distinct item no

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (Formatted text, not images.)

Comment: You can adjust the answers from https://stackoverflow.com/q/41477607/330315. Especially https://stackoverflow.com/a/41477646/330315 just remove the `order by newid()`part

Comment: `DISTINCT` always applies to the entire row, it doesn't make sense otherwise. If you want to get each value of `item` only once you can use `GROUP BY item` and produce a rule that picks one value of the possible values of `rate` for each value of `item`. GROUP BY`, however, doesn't put in the result set complete rows from the table; it **generates** the rows it puts in its result set.

Comment: All your rates are distinct within item group. How 12 is distinct in group a, for example? I think you need to clarify.

Answer (score 5):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9324a/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

Generate a table with 12 items `A` - `L` each with rates `0` - `4`:

```
CREATE TABLE items ( item, rate ) AS
SELECT CHR( 64 + CEIL( LEVEL / 5 ) ),
       MOD( LEVEL - 1, 5 )
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 60;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT item,
       rate
FROM   (
  SELECT i.*,
         -- Give the rates for each item a unique index assigned in a random order
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY item ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE ) AS rn
  FROM   items i
  ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE -- Order all the rows randomly
)
WHERE  rn = 1                -- Only get the first row for each item
AND    ROWNUM <= 10          -- Only get the first 10 items.
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9324a/3/0)**:

```
| ITEM | RATE |
|------|------|
|    A |    0 |
|    K |    2 |
|    G |    4 |
|    C |    1 |
|    E |    0 |
|    H |    0 |
|    F |    2 |
|    D |    3 |
|    L |    4 |
|    I |    1 |
```

Comment: Why is it Oracle doesn't provide a simple keyword to implement such a simple query

Comment: @Tuomas Toivonen: Just think about how you'd call this "simple keyword". `a_random_row_per_parameter1_limited_to_parameter2_random_result_rows(id,10)`?

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner. I think the pseudo-query I described in the OP is very simple expression of the desired result. The internal implementation could be arbitrarily complex, as the working examples shown here. So there's no reason why Oracle (or SQL standard) couldn't provide simple keyword for this. I understand the select statement targets single rows and doesn't keep state of it's accumulating result set, but it doesn't mean it can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

I mention table create and query for distinct and top 10 rows;
[(Ref SqlFiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8fa17/3)

```
create table foo(item varchar(20), rate int);

insert into foo values('a',50);
insert into foo values('a',12);
insert into foo values('a',26);
insert into foo values('b',12);
insert into foo values('b',15);
insert into foo values('b',45);
insert into foo values('b',10);
insert into foo values('c',5);
insert into foo values('c',15);
```

--Here first get the distinct item and then filter row number wise rows:

```
 select item, rate from (
      select item, rate, ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY item ORDER BY rate desc) 
     row_num  from foo 
 )  where row_num=1;
```

Comment: This does not limit the output to 10 rows (if there are more than 10 items) and the output is deterministic not random (as the OP's requirement).